# How to place the buttons next to Textarea without any spaces using the bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am quite new to bootstrap and CSS so I am a bit stuck in one of the issues. I tried various workarounds mentioned here but none seem to work for me so posting here. Really sorry if found a duplicate.

I am using the `Bootstrap 5.0` in my application and I am trying to create the `TextArea` and on the left side of it I would like to create 2 buttons without any spaces attached to `Textarea`.

I am assuming due to the default column spacing of the bootstrap I am getting the spaces between `button` and `textarea`. I would like to remove this. I am aware that I can use `CSS` to remove this but I would like to do the default `Bootstrap` way.

Following is the code I have:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1  padding-0">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Test1</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Test2</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-11  padding-0">
      <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried various things like `no-gutters` and `float-end` but nothing seems to work. Can anyone please let me know how can I achieve this using `Bootstrap`?

Following is the current page I have (Based on the above code I have this currently):

[image]

Following is my goal ( I would like my HTML page to appear like this):

[image]

Comment: `col-md-1` is wider than the buttons, try aligning the contents of the button rows to the right.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Thanks for your response. I tried `float-right`, `float-end`, `pull-right` etc but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without `.row` and `.col` class and used flexbox for that

```css
textarea {
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<div class="d-flex p-5">    
  <div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Test1</button>       
    <br/>      
   <button class="btn btn-primary">Test2</button>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
```

With `.row` and `.col`

```css
textarea {
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row g-0 p-5">    
  <div class="col-auto">
   <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Test1</button>       
    <br/>      
   <button class="btn btn-primary">Test2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. If incase I would like to use `row` and `col` then how can I achieve this? Because my other parts of the applications are wrapped within the `row` and `col` so I was planning to use the same to have properly structured code. Can you please suggest some work-around for achieving this with `row` and `col` in `Bootstrap`? Thanks a lot in-advance.

Comment: I have updated my answer. please check it